# How to get a keyboard code for an Android project?

Tags: android, logging, keyboard, key, hardware

i'm trying to check a condition which says:

```
  keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
  Log.e("key",keyCode+"");
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    //logic
```

On the log window, the 'keyCode' arent getting any keyboard code, except the value from KEYCODE_DEL which is 67 but doing this ONLY if the EditText is empty!

```
    editTextPrincipal.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
            Log.e("key",keyCode+"");
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                usuarioDeletouCaracter = true;
                return usuarioDeletouCaracter;
            }
            return usuarioDeletouCaracter;

        }
    });

    editTextPrincipal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!usuarioDeletouCaracter){
                editTextPrincipal.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "O usuario apagou", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

wherever a key is pressed on the keybaord, the keycode on the log window, should returns her value but this is not happen =\

Answer (score 0):

Soft keyboards almost never generate keycodes.  Either use a TextWatcher, or you're going to have to override the InputConnection object.

Comment: i've already read this which you said before but i didnt get something: i'm using the main keyboard provided from my android phone that are a Moto G3 with an original ROM.

Comment: Doesn't matter.  It most likely doesn't send keycodes.  I have no idea what the main keyboard for a specific model is, but I can tell you that google's LatinIME (the most likely answer) does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
editTextPrincipal.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
Log.e("key",keyCode);
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
                usuarioDeletouCaracter = true;
                return usuarioDeletouCaracter;
            }
     return usuarioDeletouCaracter;
}
});
```

reference https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html

Comment: will not work. i cant call the function onkeyDown inside an instance to the class setOnKeyListener